# Open div popup after clicking tr row in generated ajax table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having troubles with my javascript after generating my table with AJAX.
I am generating a table with user inserted values. The values are retrieved from an SQL EXPRESS 2012 database which is run locally. When the values have been retrieved they are stored in a string. That string is being send back to the index.thml. All the result retrieving is being done by validate.php.

I have tried my code with a normal table and it works like a charm. But whenever i use a generated table it seems to refuse to run the javascript.

My personal thoughts about this is because the table does not exist when the page is loaded. The table is created after the page is loaded which causes the javascript not to run properly. I had the same problem with the highlighting of the row when mouseover. I have overcome this problem by calling the mouseover function in the tr.mouseover.

To be really honest i am new to ajax and javascript so almost everything I have right now has come from the internet. I do know what everything means and have altered the code for my project. I really hope you guys can shine a bright light on this because I have been stuck for several days.

So let's begin:

my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ESL Checking Tool</title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxrequest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callAjax(method, value, target)
        {
            if(encodeURIComponent) 
            {
                var req = new AjaxRequest();
                var params = "method=" + method + "&value=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "&target=" + target;
                req.setMethod("POST");
                req.loadXMLDoc('validate.php', params);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mouseover() 
        {
            var message = $('#message');
            var tr = $('#table_id').find('tr');

            tr.hover(
                function() 
                {  //mouseover
                    $(this).addClass('row-highlight');
                    var values = '';
                    var tds = $(this).find('td');

                    $.each(tds, function(index, item) 
                    {
                        values = values + 'td' + (index + 1) + ':' + item.innerHTML + '<br/>';
                    });
                    message.html(values);
                },
                function() 
                {  // mouseout
                    $(this).removeClass('row-highlight');
                    message.html('');
                })
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="dt_example">
<form method="POST" action="non-Ajax form handler" onsubmit="return checkForm(this;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ESL Checkup Form</legend>

        <p>Product: <input type="text" size="32" id="product" name="product" onkeyup="if(this.value != '') callAjax('checkProduct', this.value, this.id);">
        <input id="valid_product" type="checkbox" disabled name="valid_product"></p>
        <div id="rsp_product">
        </div>

        <p>Barcode: <input type="text" size="32" id="barcode" name="barcode" onkeyup="if(this.value != '') callAjax('checkBarcode', this.value, this.id);">
        <input id="valid_barcode" type="checkbox" disabled name="valid_barcode"></p>
        <div id="rsp_barcode"><!-- --></div>

        <p>ESL: <input type="text" size="32" id="email" name="email" onkeyup="if(this.value != '') callAjax('checkEmail', this.value, this.id);">
        <input id="valid_email" type="checkbox" disabled name="valid_email"></p>
        <div id="rsp_email"><!-- --></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="message">
</div>
<a href="#" class="topopup">Click Here Trigger</a>
<div id="toPopup"> 
    <div class="close"></div>
    <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
    <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->
        <p>
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, 
        feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi 
        vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, 
        commodo Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique 
        senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, 
        feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. </p>
        <br />
        <p>
        Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi 
        vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, 
        commodo Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </p>
        <p align="center"><a href="#" class="livebox">Click Here Trigger</a></p>
    </div> <!--your content end-->

</div> <!--toPopup end-->

<div class="loader"></div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my style/style.css:

```
/* 
author: istockphp.com
*/
#backgroundPopup { 
z-index:1;
position: fixed;
display:none;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background:#000000; 
top:0px;  
left:0px;
}
#toPopup {
font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 10px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
color: #333333;
display: none;
font-size: 14px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -402px;
position: fixed;
top: 20%;
width: 800px;
z-index: 2;
}
div.loader {
background: url("../img/loading.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 32px;
width: 32px;
display: none;
z-index: 9999;
top: 40%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -10px;
}
div.close {
background: url("../img/closebox.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
bottom: 24px;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
height: 30px;
left: 27px;
position: relative;
width: 30px;
}
span.ecs_tooltip {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: none;
font-size: 11px;
height: 16px;
opacity: 0.7;
padding: 4px 3px 2px 5px;
position: absolute;
right: -62px;
text-align: center;
top: -51px;
width: 93px;
}
span.arrow {
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-top: 7px solid #000000;
display: block;
height: 1px;
left: 40px;
position: relative;
top: 3px;
width: 1px;
}
div#popup_content {
margin: 4px 7px;
}
.row-highlight {
background-color: #0099FF;
}
```

my ajaxrequest.js:

```
function AjaxRequest()
{
    var req;
    var method="GET";
    var nocache=false;
    var handler;
    this.loadXMLDoc=function(url,params)
        {
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                    try
                    {
                        req=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                        req=false;
                    }
            }
            else if(window.ActiveXObject)
            {
                try
                {
                    req=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        req=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                        req=false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(req)
            {
                if(!handler)handler=processReqChange;req.onreadystatechange=handler;if(nocache)
                {
                    params+=(params!='')?'&'+(new Date()).getTime():(new Date()).getTime();
                }
                if(method=="POST")
                {
                    req.open("POST",url,true);
                    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    req.send(params);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(params)url+="?"+ params;req.open(method,url,true);req.send(null);
                }
            return true;
            }
        return false;
        }
        this.setMethod=function(newmethod)
        {
            method=newmethod.toUpperCase();
        }
        this.nocache=function()
        {
            nocache=true;
        }
        this.setHandler=function(fn)
        {
            handler=fn;
        }
        this.getResponse=function()
        {
            return req;
        }
        var getNodeValue=function(parent,tagName)
        {
            var node=parent.getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0];
            return(node&&node.firstChild)?node.firstChild.nodeValue:'';
        }
        var processReqChange=function()
        {
            if(req.readyState==4&&req.status==200)
            {
                var response=req.responseXML.documentElement;
                var commands=response.getElementsByTagName('command');
                for(var i=0;i<commands.length;i++)
                {
                    method=commands[i].getAttribute('method');
                    switch(method)
                    {
                        case'alert':var message=getNodeValue(commands[i],'message');
                        window.alert(message);
                        break;
                        case'setvalue':var target=getNodeValue(commands[i],'target');
                        var value=getNodeValue(commands[i],'value');
                        if(target&&value!=null)
                        {
                            document.getElementById(target).value=value;
                        }
                        break;
                        case'setdefault':var target=getNodeValue(commands[i],'target');
                        if(target)
                        {
                            document.getElementById(target).value=document.getElementById(target).defaultValue;
                        }
                        break;
                        case'focus':var target=getNodeValue(commands[i],'target');
                        if(target)
                        {
                            document.getElementById(target).focus();
                        }
                        break;
                        case'setcontent':var target=getNodeValue(commands[i],'target');
                        var content=getNodeValue(commands[i],'content');
                        if(target&&(content!=null))
                        {
                            document.getElementById(target).innerHTML=content;
                        }
                        break;
                        case'setstyle':var target=getNodeValue(commands[i],'target');
                        var property=getNodeValue(commands[i],'property');
                        var value=getNodeValue(commands[i],'value');
                        if(target&&property&&(value!=null))
                        {
                            document.getElementById(target).style[property]=value;
                        }
                        break;
                        case'setproperty':var target=getNodeValue(commands[i],'target');
                        var property=getNodeValue(commands[i],'property');
                        var value=getNodeValue(commands[i],'value');
                        if(value=="true")value=true;
                        if(value=="false")value=false;
                        if(target&&document.getElementById(target))
                        {
                            document.getElementById(target)[property]=value;
                        }
                        break;
                        default:window.console.log("Error: unrecognised method '"+ method+"' in processReqChange()");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

my script.js:

```
/* 
author: istockphp.com
*/
jQuery(function($) {

$("a.topopup").click(function() {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
            loadPopup(); // function show popup 
        }, 500); // .5 second
return false;
});

$("tr#row-clck").click(function() {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
            loadPopup(); // function show popup 
        }, 500); // .5 second
return false;
});

/* event for close the popup */
$("div.close").hover(
                function() {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                },
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                }
            );

$("div.close").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$(this).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    }   
});

$("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$('a.livebox').click(function() {
    alert('Hello World!');
return false;
});


 /************** start: functions. **************/
function tablerowclick() {
    loading(); // loading
    setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(); // function show popup 
        }, 500); // .5 second
return false;
}

function loading() {
    $("div.loader").show();  
}
function closeloading() {
    $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');  
}

var popupStatus = 0; // set value

function loadPopup() { 
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }   
}

function disablePopup() {
    if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
        popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
    }
}
/************** end: functions. **************/
}); // jQuery End
```

my validate.php:

```
<?PHP
// check that all POST variables have been set
if(!isset($_POST['method']) || !$method = $_POST['method']) exit;
if(!isset($_POST['value']) || !$value = $_POST['value']) exit;
if(!isset($_POST['target']) || !$target = $_POST['target']) exit;

$serverName = "localhost\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"MIQ", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"miq123");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
}else{
   echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$passed = false;
$retval = '';

switch($method)
{
    case 'checkProduct':
    $query = "SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, ESL, Product FROM ESL, SIQEE_IM_ITEM_INFORMATION WHERE ESL.Product = SIQEE_IM_ITEM_INFORMATION.GTIN AND SIQEE_IM_ITEM_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%$value%'";
    //Execute query
    $qry_result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered")) or die(sqlsrv_error());
    //Build Result String
    $display_string = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="table_id" width="60%">';
    $display_string .= "<thead>";
    $display_string .= "<tr>";
    $display_string .= "<th>ESL</th>";
    $display_string .= "<th>Barcode</th>";
    $display_string .= "<th>Product</th>";
    $display_string .= "</tr>";
    $display_string .= "</thead>";
    $display_string .= "<tbody>";

    // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry_result)){
    $display_string .= "<tr id='row-clck' onmouseover='mouseover();'>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ESL]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[Product]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[PRODUCT_NAME]</td>";-
    $display_string .= "</tr>";

    }
    $display_string .= "</tbody>";
    $display_string .= "</table>";
    $num_results = sqlsrv_num_rows($qry_result); 
    if ($num_results > 0){
        $retval = $display_string;
        $passed = true;
    }
    else{
    $retval = "Dit product is nog niet gekoppeld";
    $passed = false;
    }
      // ...
    // set the $retval message, and the $passed variable to true or false
    // ...
    break;

    case 'checkBarcode':
    $query = "SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, ESL, Product FROM ESL, SIQEE_IM_ITEM_INFORMATION WHERE ESL.Product = '$value' AND SIQEE_IM_ITEM_INFORMATION.GTIN = '$value'";
    //Execute query
    $qry_result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered")) or die(sqlsrv_error());
    //Build Result String
    $display_string = "<table>";
    $display_string .= "<tr>";
    $display_string .= "<th>ESL</th>";
    $display_string .= "<th>Barcode</th>";
    $display_string .= "<th>Product</th>";
    $display_string .= "</tr>";

    // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry_result)){
    $display_string .= "<tr>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ESL]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[Product]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[PRODUCT_NAME]</td>";-
    $display_string .= "</tr>";

    }
    $display_string .= "</table>";
    $num_results = sqlsrv_num_rows($qry_result); 
    if ($num_results > 0){
        $retval = $display_string;
        $passed = true;
    }
    else{
    $retval = "Deze barcode is nog niet gekoppeld";
    $passed = false;
    }
    // ...
    // set the $retval message, and the $passed variable to true or false
    // ...
    break;
    case 'checkAge':
    if ($value >= 16 && $value <= 100){
    $retval = "is helemaal goed";
    $passed = true;
    }
    else{
    $retval = "Nope no can do";
    $passed = false; 
    }
    // ...
    // set the $retval message, and the $passed variable to true or false
    // ...
    break;

    case 'checkEmail':
    //build query
            $query2 = "SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, ESL, Product FROM ESL, SIQEE_IM_ITEM_INFORMATION WHERE ESL.ESL = '$value' AND SIQEE_IM_ITEM_INFORMATION.GTIN = ESL.Product";
    //Execute query
    $qry_result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query2, array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered")) or die(sqlsrv_error());
    //Build Result String
    $display_string = "<table>";
    $display_string .= "<tr>";
    $display_string .= "<th>ESL</th>";
    $display_string .= "<th>Barcode</th>";
    $display_string .= "<th>Product</th>";
    $display_string .= "</tr>";

    // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry_result2)){
    $display_string .= "<tr>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ESL]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[Product]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[PRODUCT_NAME]</td>";-
    $display_string .= "</tr>";

    }
    $display_string .= "</table>";
    $num_results2 = sqlsrv_num_rows($qry_result2); 
    if ($num_results2 > 0){
        $retval = $display_string;
        $passed = true;
    }
    else{
    $retval = "Deze ESL is nog niet gekoppeld";
    $passed = false;
    }
    // ...
    // set the $retval message, and the $passed variable to true or false
    // ...
    break;

    default: exit;
}

include "class.xmlresponse.php";
$xml = new xmlResponse();
$xml->start();

// set the response text
$xml->command('setcontent',
array('target' => "rsp_$target", 'content' => htmlentities($retval))
);

if($passed) {
// set the message colour to green and the checkbox to checked

$xml->command('setstyle',
  array('target' => "rsp_$target", 'property' => 'color', 'value' => 'green')
);
$xml->command('setproperty',
  array('target' => "valid_$target", 'property' => 'checked', 'value' => 'true')
);

} else {
// set the message colour to red, the checkbox to unchecked and focus back on the field

$xml->command('setstyle',
  array('target' => "rsp_$target", 'property' => 'color', 'value' => 'red')
);
$xml->command('setproperty',
  array('target' => "valid_$target", 'property' => 'checked', 'value' => 'false')
);
$xml->command('focus', array('target' => $target));

}

$xml->end();
?>
```

Comment: So much code! But yes, you need to delegate events for newly added elements, look into jQuery's `.on()`

Comment: How do I delegate events for newly added elements? The table is returned in a string. Do I need to add a call to a function in the string. 

I have looked in the .on() but it doesn't really make sense to me because the .on() is still defined premature, as in before the table is actually created.

Comment: Yes, so you bind to an element that already exists (`document` is always a safe bet) and then target your newly added element. So if you're table has an ID of `newTable`, the event would be: `$(document).on("click", "#newTable", function () {} );`

Comment: I am sorry but that suggestion is still not working. I have updated the event with your suggestion but my table has an ID of table_id.

Still nothing happens when i click a row.

Answer (score 1):

`$("tr#row-clck").click(function() {});` will work only for elements that are presents when the function is defined.

You have to call your function in a more global way like

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr#row-clck', function() {  
     /* your code */ 
});
```

Comment: I have updated my function with the call to the document. But still it gives me nothing whenever i click a row in the generated table.

Answer (score 0):

As j_freyre said and as you mentioned, the click event seems to be bound before your table is created. (Since your AJAX-Call is async this seems to be the cause).

```
 req.open("POST",url,true); //the true marks it as asynchronous
```

You can define and bind the click-event in the callback function of your Ajax-Call. This would be in your ajaxrequest.js somewhere around this code

```
case'setcontent':var target=getNodeValue(commands[i],'target');
                    var content=getNodeValue(commands[i],'content');
                    if(target&&(content!=null))
                    {
                        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML=content;
                        //Your logic for binding the event e.g. $("tr#id").on('click',...)
                    }
                    break;
```